# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' portfoliobusiness.php on line 41

Tags: php, parsing

I am writing a code to filter a bunch of gallery images using the tags assigned to the images. However I am running into this parse error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

I am baffled coz I see that the "}" it is referring to has been opened and closed correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the line thats throwing the error

```
<button class="cbp-filter-item"><?php if($key == 0){echo 'cbp-filter-item-active'};?> data-filter=".<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$tag)); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($tag); ?></button> ","-",$tag)); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($tag); ?></button>
```

Here's the code snippet
    
        >

```
        <?php if(isset($tagsFilter) && count($tagsFilter)): 
            foreach($tagsFilter as $key=>$tag): 
        ?>
        <button class="cbp-filter-item"><?php if($key == 0){echo 'cbp-filter-item-active'};?> data-filter=".<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$tag)); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($tag); ?></button>
        <?php endforeach; endif;?>
    </div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sai.

Comment: `};` <-- Look at this again also what should that be: `","-",$tag)); ?>` A half eaten php line?

Comment: `{echo 'cbp-filter-item-active'}` → `{echo 'cbp-filter-item-active';}`, perhaps. But what have you got against line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<?php if($key == 0){echo 'cbp-filter-item-active'};?>
```

With this one:

```
<?php if($key == 0){echo 'cbp-filter-item-active';} ?>
```

Comment: Ok I have changed it to   `<button class="cbp-filter-item"><?php if($key == 0){echo 'cbp-filter-item-active';}?> data-filter=".<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$tag)); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($tag); ?></button> `     Now it says unexpected Endif in the line `?php endforeach; endif;?>1

Comment: since you didn't put all your script here I can only guess this is what you want: `<?php if(isset($tagsFilter) && count($tagsFilter)): foreach($tagsFilter as $key=>$tag): ?>
 <button class="cbp-filter-item <?php if($key == 0){echo 'cbp-filter-item-active';}?>" data-filter=".<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$tag)); ?>">
  <?php echo ucfirst($tag); ?>
 </button>
<?php endforeach; endif;?>`

Comment: Sorry for being vague. What I have been trying to do is to filter a set of items based on the k2 tags on my joomla site. Make the first tag active and show the items under it. The parsing error is resolved now but I cannot get the desired result.   [Here is the complete script](http://pastebin.com/vJaxHgH9)